# Typescript: express function instance property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a JS function

```
function someMethod (arg1: boolean) {
  this.state = { };

  // logic and stuff
  return arg1;
```

How can `state` be expressed in Typescript?

```
someMethod(true);
someMethod.state; // Property 'state' does not exist on type '(arg1: boolean) => boolean'
```

Comment: The property `state` doesn't exist on your function. It would exist on newly constructed objects using `someMethod` as a constructor (i.e. `new someMethod(true)`), but not on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `someMethod` to be a normal function that also has a property, you could simply declare it as having both a call signature and properties, like this:

```
declare const someMethod: {
  (arg1: boolean): boolean;
  state: any; // or whatever type you intend someMethod.state to have
}
```

However, if `someMethod` is actually meant to be used as a constructor function, I'd strongly recommend rewriting this as a [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) instead:

```
declare class someClass {
  constructor(arg1: boolean);
  state: any;
}
```

And then use it like this (note the `new` keyword):

```
const instance = new someClass(true);
instance.state = {};
```

Comment: I sort of chalked this up to a bad pattern in the first place. Good to have reaffirmation and thanks for the answer.